# Change Add to cart button text for specific products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

In woocommerce I have been able to change all the "Add to cart" buttons text to "+", using the code below:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 
'wh_archive_custom_cart_button_text');   // 2.1 +

function wh_archive_custom_cart_button_text()
{
    return __('+', 'woocommerce');
}
```

But now I would like to change the button text for specific products to *(lowercase)* "add to cart".

Some help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will change add to cart button text depending on defined product IDs:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_loop_add_to_cart_button', 20, 2 ); 
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button_text, $product ) {
    // HERE define your specific product IDs in this array
    $specific_ids = array(37, 40, 53);
    
    if( in_array($product->get_id(), $specific_ids) ) {
        $button_text = __("add to cart", "woocommerce");
    } else {
        $button_text = __('+', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change add to cart button text of a specific product without coding, here is the solution.

1. .postid-1324 => Product id
2. .single_add_to_cart_button => add to cart button class

```css
.postid-1324 .single_add_to_cart_button:after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(106,191,119);
    width: 110px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.postid-1324 .single_add_to_cart_button:before {
    content: 'add money to wallet';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999998;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an edited version of @LoicTheAztec 's code to apply it to single product page instances by editing the filter on the first line:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_single_loop_add_to_cart_button', 20, 2 ); 
function custom_single_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button_text, $product ) {
    // HERE define your specific product IDs in this array
    $specific_ids = array(37, 40, 53);

    if( in_array($product->get_id(), $specific_ids) ) {
        $button_text = __("add to cart", "woocommerce");
    } else {
        $button_text = __('+', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

I ended up adding both the product archives page version (LoicTheAztec's code) and this single product page version to my functions.php file to cover all instances of a particular product.
See this documentation from WooCommerce about the woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text filter: https://woocommerce.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/

Answer (score 0):

When I tried @coneofvision's answer, it changes ALL of the products "Add to Cart" buttons despite specifying the post IDs.

The below code works and only changes the specified product IDs:

```
/**
 * Changes the add to cart button text for a specific product ID on the single product page and product archives page.
 *
 * @param string $text The default add to cart button text.
 * @param object $product The WooCommerce product object.
 * @return string The updated add to cart button text.
 */
function custom_add_to_cart_button_text_single( $text, $product ) {
    $product_id = 123; // Replace with the product ID for which you want to change the button text
    if( $product->get_id() === $product_id ) {
        $text = __( 'New Add to Cart Button Text for Product ID '.$product_id, 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $text;
}

/**
 * Changes the add to cart button text for a specific product ID on the product archives page.
 *
 * @param string $text The default add to cart button text.
 * @param object $product The WooCommerce product object.
 * @return string The updated add to cart button text.
 */
function custom_add_to_cart_button_text_archives( $text, $product ) {
    $product_id = 123; // Replace with the product ID for which you want to change the button text
    if( $product->get_id() === $product_id ) {
        $text = __( 'New Add to Cart Button Text for Product ID '.$product_id, 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $text;
}

// Changes the add-to-cart text on the single product page for a specific product ID.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_button_text_single', 10, 2 ); 

// Changes the add-to-cart text on the product archives page for a specific product ID.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_button_text_archives', 10, 2 );
```

This code adds two filter functions, custom_add_to_cart_button_text_single, and custom_add_to_cart_button_text_archives, which change the add-to-cart button text for a specific product ID on the single product page and product archives page, respectively.

You can use this code to modify the button text for any product ID by replacing the value of the $product_id variable with the desired product ID.

To use this code, you need to add it to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin file. Once the code is added, the new add to cart button text will be displayed for the corresponding product ID on the single product page and product archives page.