# Put two php functions together (to change add-to-cart button in woocommerce)

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to implement the code in this answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176613/change-add-to-cart-button-text-for-specific-products-in-woocommerce.) by @LoicTheAztec to change the add-to-cart button text for specific products. I've tried that code and it works perfectly by itself.

But I have an earlier implemented custom code (see below) to change the add-to-cart button text when the product is already in the cart which also works by itself, and which I want to keep. But when both codes are activated they don't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $class_to_append = "selected";
    
    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        
        if( get_the_ID() == $_product->id ) {
            return __('✓ already selected', 'woocommerce');
        }         
    }
    
    return __('Add to Cart', 'woocommerce');
}
```

I've tried to put these two pieces of code into one function so that they work together but whatever I've tried I'm doing it wrong because it breaks my site.

This is what I want to achieve:

1. The add-to-cart button text is changed to "go to checkout" for specified products (and doesn't change when item is in the cart).
2. For all other products, the button text is set to "Add to Cart". When the item is in the cart, the button text is changed to "already selected".

If anyone can help me with this, that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revised your code. Try the below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {

    global $woocommerce;
    $class_to_append = "selected";
    $specified_products = array( 82, 74 ); // add your specified products ids.
    
    if( is_product_in_cart( get_the_ID() ) && !in_array( get_the_ID(), $specified_products ) ) {
        return __('✓ already selected', 'woocommerce');
    }elseif ( is_product_in_cart( get_the_ID() ) && in_array( get_the_ID(), $specified_products ) ) {
        return __('go to checkout', 'woocommerce');
    }else{
        return __('Add to Cart', 'woocommerce');
    }

}
```

You can make a small function to check whether your product is in the cart or not.

```
function is_product_in_cart( $product_id ) {

    $in_cart = false;
  
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];
        if ( $product_in_cart === $product_id ){
            $in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }
  
    if ( $in_cart ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it works. Only I think one part was not clear from my original question. I want that the "go to checkout" text is always there for the specified products (not when these products are in the cart. But based on your answer I could fix it myself by changing this: ```elseif ( in_array( get_the_ID(), $specified_products ) ) {
        return __('go to checkout', 'woocommerce');```

Comment: I will anyway accept your answer as it helped me resolve the problem. but maybe you want to just change the code for any future assistance to someone else who might be looking for this answer :)